# Qt-QSqlite : Not able to fetch the record if only one record is present

Tags: qt

Sorry I posted this query again...

My Original query was:

I am trying to fetch the records from the table. I am able to get all the records except the first record.

Same way if there is only one record, then that record is also not fetched.

How could I get the only record present in my table.

I am using Qt, QSqlite and trying to get the records using `QSqlQuery.next()` function.

Like:

```
while(query.next())
```

.............................................................................

I have only 1 record in Database like :UserId = 1 and Name = Naveen.
To get this record I tried like:

```
strQuery = QString("select Name from User_Table where UserID = 1"); 
if (!ExecuteQuery(strQuery, sqlQuery)) 
{ 
     qDebug() << sqlQuery.lastError(); 
     return false; 
} 

while (sqlQuery.next()) 
{ 
     QString strName = sqlQuery.value(0).toString(); 
}
```

This way I didn't get the Name Naveen.I tried to debug, but that while loop never executes –

Any suggestions on this, please... Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for your ExecuteQuery function?

Comment: I am not able to format the postings... How to format while adding comments...!!! :(

Comment: `ExecuteQuery(QString strQuery, QSqlQuery & sqlQuery)`
`{` 
 `if (!m_DB.isOpen())`
 `{`
  `if (!OpenDB())`
   `return false;`
 `}`

 `bool bError = false;`
     `sqlQuery =  m_DB.exec(strQuery);`
 `QSqlError rSqlError = m_DB.lastError();`
 `bError = rSqlError.isValid();`
     `qDebug() << "Query Executed: " << sqlQuery.executedQuery();`

 `if (bError)`
        `qDebug() << "Last Error: " << sqlQuery.lastError();`

 `return !bError;`
`}`

Comment: You can edit your question to add that code, rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, if you change your while loop to

```
do
{
    QString strName = sqlQuery.value(0).toString();
} while (sqlQuery.next());
```

does it work? If so it means that something already calls QSqlQuery::next() or QSqlQuery::first() before your loop.